# C++ - finding unicode characters in UTF-16 encoded string

Tags: c++, unicode, find

So, I'm doing OCR and sending the results to a string, and I'm trying to filter the results--in this case, Vision will often render the window buttons as things like "OX". It occasionally renders them in Unicode characters, so I need to be able to `string.find` those instances. Bear in mind that I'm working with someone else's code, but I'm pretty sure that by the time I'm doing my `finds`, the `finalTextRaw` string has been converted to UTF-16. These existing `finds` I've made for ASCII text work great, but I can't seem to figure out the syntax I'd need to search for Unicode characters within those UTF-16 strings. I tried using a Unicode -> UTF-16 conversion tool and `finding` various iterations of its results, but that didn't seem to do the trick.

While I'm at it, since I'll probably end up doing a bunch of these as I test and discover all the different kinds of garbage Vision will send, might there be a more compact way of doing this than a million `else ifs`?

```
if (!textArea.text.empty()) textArea.text += "\n";
textArea.text += finalText;
textArea.rawText += finalTextRaw;
utf8::utf8to16(finalTextRaw.begin(), finalTextRaw.end(), back_inserter(textArea.wideText));
textArea.m_rect = totalRect;

if (finalTextRaw.find("RetroArch") != finalTextRaw.npos ) ///don't capture title bar
{
    LogMsg("Found RA");
}
else if (finalTextRaw.find("OX") != finalTextRaw.npos)
{
    LogMsg("Found window buttons");
```

Comment: Unicode characters 0-127 are US-ASCII, and 128+ are non-ASCII. Are you asking how to search what is effectively an array of integer values, for values above 127?

Comment: Well, when I perform the above `finds`, I'm just typing in ASCII text. If I want to search for ロ×, `find("ロ×")` does not work--or at least, Visual Studio tells me I'd have to convert the entire project, and I certainly don't know whether doing that would break something.

Comment: The syntax for a Unicode string is U"...". However, that's a `std::u32string`, and not UTF-16. but, UTF-16 is trivially convertible to UTF-32.

Comment: So, I just backed up my project and converted the files to Unicode so I'm able to perform the `find("ロ×")` command. Unfortunately, that's not correctly detecting anything. So, do you think I'll need to convert all the strings to u32 for that to work?

Comment: C++ source does not necessarily itself has to be in Unicode, in order to use Unicode strings in the C++ source. I routinely use literal UTF-32 in my C++ source, which is encoded in bog-standard UTF-8. For more information, see your C++ textbook.